# can flink on k8s use pv using NFS and pvc as the high avalibility storageDir

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, high-availability

I want to deploy Flink 1.12.0 on k8s with HA mode, and I don't want to deploy the HDFS cluster, and I have an NFS so that I am created a PV that use NFS as the backend storage, and I created a PVC for Deployment mount.

this is my FLINK configMap

```yaml
kubernetes.cluster-id: mta-flink
high-availability: org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability. KubernetesHaServicesFactory
high-availability.storageDir: file:///opt/flink/nfs/ha
```

and this is my jobmanager yaml file:

```yaml
volumeMounts:

name: flink-config-volume
mountPath: /opt/flink/conf
name: flink-nfs
mountPath: /opt/flink/nfs
securityContext:
runAsUser: 9999 # refers to user flink from official flink image, change if necessary
#fsGroup: 9999
volumes:
name: flink-config-volume
configMap:
name: mta-flink-config
items:
key: flink-conf.yaml
path: flink-conf.yaml
key: log4j-console.properties
path: log4j-console.properties
name: flink-nfs
persistentVolumeClaim:
claimName: mta-flink-nfs-pvc
```

It can be deployed successfully, but if I browser the jobmanager:8081 website, I get the result below:

```
{"errors": ["Service temporarily unavailable due to an ongoing leader election. Please refresh."]}
```

is the PVC can be used as `high-availability.storageDir`?  if it's can be used, how can I fix this error?

the logs of jobmanager shows that the leader is elected already:

```
2020-12-29T06:45:54.177850394Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,177 DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.extended.leaderelection.LeaderElector [] - Leader election started
2020-12-29T06:45:54.177855303Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,177 DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.extended.leaderelection.LeaderElector [] - Attempting to acquire leader lease 'ConfigMapLock: default - mta-flink-resourcemanager-leader (6f6479c6-86cc-4d62-84f9-37ff968bd0e5)'...
2020-12-29T06:45:54.178668055Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,178 DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.WatchConnectionManager [] - WebSocket successfully opened
2020-12-29T06:45:54.178895963Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,178 INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderretrieval.DefaultLeaderRetrievalService [] - Starting DefaultLeaderRetrievalService with KubernetesLeaderRetrievalDriver{configMapName='mta-flink-resourcemanager-leader'}.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.179327491Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,179 DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.WatchConnectionManager [] - Connecting websocket ... io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.WatchConnectionManager@6d303498
2020-12-29T06:45:54.230081993Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,229 DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.WatchConnectionManager [] - WebSocket successfully opened
2020-12-29T06:45:54.230202329Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,230 INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderretrieval.DefaultLeaderRetrievalService [] - Starting DefaultLeaderRetrievalService with KubernetesLeaderRetrievalDriver{configMapName='mta-flink-dispatcher-leader'}.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.230219281Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,229 DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.WatchConnectionManager [] - WebSocket successfully opened
2020-12-29T06:45:54.230353912Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,230 INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderelection.DefaultLeaderElectionService [] - Starting DefaultLeaderElectionService with KubernetesLeaderElectionDriver{configMapName='mta-flink-resourcemanager-leader'}.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.237004177Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,236 DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.extended.leaderelection.LeaderElector [] - Leader changed from null to 6f6479c6-86cc-4d62-84f9-37ff968bd0e5
2020-12-29T06:45:54.237024655Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,236 INFO org.apache.flink.kubernetes.kubeclient.resources.KubernetesLeaderElector [] - New leader elected 6f6479c6-86cc-4d62-84f9-37ff968bd0e5 for mta-flink-restserver-leader.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.237027811Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,236 DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.extended.leaderelection.LeaderElector [] - Successfully Acquired leader lease 'ConfigMapLock: default - mta-flink-restserver-leader (6f6479c6-86cc-4d62-84f9-37ff968bd0e5)'
2020-12-29T06:45:54.237297376Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,237 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderelection.DefaultLeaderElectionService [] - Grant leadership to contender http://mta-flink-jobmanager:8081 with session ID 9587e13f-322f-4cd5-9fff-b4941462be0f.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.237353551Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,237 INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.DispatcherRestEndpoint [] - http://mta-flink-jobmanager:8081 was granted leadership with leaderSessionID=9587e13f-322f-4cd5-9fff-b4941462be0f
2020-12-29T06:45:54.237440354Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,237 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderelection.DefaultLeaderElectionService [] - Confirm leader session ID 9587e13f-322f-4cd5-9fff-b4941462be0f for leader http://mta-flink-jobmanager:8081.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.254555127Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,254 DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.extended.leaderelection.LeaderElector [] - Leader changed from null to 6f6479c6-86cc-4d62-84f9-37ff968bd0e5
2020-12-29T06:45:54.254588299Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,254 INFO org.apache.flink.kubernetes.kubeclient.resources.KubernetesLeaderElector [] - New leader elected 6f6479c6-86cc-4d62-84f9-37ff968bd0e5 for mta-flink-resourcemanager-leader.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.254628053Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,254 DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.extended.leaderelection.LeaderElector [] - Successfully Acquired leader lease 'ConfigMapLock: default - mta-flink-resourcemanager-leader (6f6479c6-86cc-4d62-84f9-37ff968bd0e5)'
2020-12-29T06:45:54.254871569Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,254 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderelection.DefaultLeaderElectionService [] - Grant leadership to contender LeaderContender: StandaloneResourceManager with session ID b1730dc6-0f94-49f4-b519-56917f3027b7.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.256608291Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,256 DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.extended.leaderelection.LeaderElector [] - Attempting to renew leader lease 'ConfigMapLock: default - mta-flink-resourcemanager-leader (6f6479c6-86cc-4d62-84f9-37ff968bd0e5)'...
2020-12-29T06:45:54.259155793Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,258 DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.extended.leaderelection.LeaderElector [] - Leader changed from null to 6f6479c6-86cc-4d62-84f9-37ff968bd0e5
2020-12-29T06:45:54.259176091Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,258 INFO org.apache.flink.kubernetes.kubeclient.resources.KubernetesLeaderElector [] - New leader elected 6f6479c6-86cc-4d62-84f9-37ff968bd0e5 for mta-flink-dispatcher-leader.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.25918096Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,259 DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.extended.leaderelection.LeaderElector [] - Successfully Acquired leader lease 'ConfigMapLock: default - mta-flink-dispatcher-leader (6f6479c6-86cc-4d62-84f9-37ff968bd0e5)'
2020-12-29T06:45:54.259362149Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,259 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderelection.DefaultLeaderElectionService [] - Grant leadership to contender LeaderContender: DefaultDispatcherRunner with session ID fbbaa883-69f6-43df-9ca0-c646bc1baad1.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.260301799Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,260 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.runner.DefaultDispatcherRunner [] - Create new DispatcherLeaderProcess with leader session id fbbaa883-69f6-43df-9ca0-c646bc1baad1.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.266724597Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,266 INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.runner.SessionDispatcherLeaderProcess [] - Start SessionDispatcherLeaderProcess.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.267718418Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,267 DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.extended.leaderelection.LeaderElector [] - Attempting to renew leader lease 'ConfigMapLock: default - mta-flink-dispatcher-leader (6f6479c6-86cc-4d62-84f9-37ff968bd0e5)'...
2020-12-29T06:45:54.26786349Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,267 INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.runner.SessionDispatcherLeaderProcess [] - Recover all persisted job graphs.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.267976912Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,267 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.DefaultJobGraphStore [] - Retrieving all stored job ids from KubernetesStateHandleStore{configMapName='mta-flink-dispatcher-leader'}.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.277681598Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,277 INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - ResourceManager akka.tcp://flink@mta-flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_0 was granted leadership with fencing token b51956917f3027b7b1730dc60f9449f4
2020-12-29T06:45:54.280411279Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,280 INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.slotmanager.SlotManagerImpl [] - Starting the SlotManager.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.281367931Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,281 DEBUG org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesLeaderElectionDriver [] - Successfully wrote leader information: Leader=http://mta-flink-jobmanager:8081, session ID=9587e13f-322f-4cd5-9fff-b4941462be0f.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.281528772Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,281 DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.extended.leaderelection.LeaderElector [] - Attempting to renew leader lease 'ConfigMapLock: default - mta-flink-restserver-leader (6f6479c6-86cc-4d62-84f9-37ff968bd0e5)'...
2020-12-29T06:45:54.286191344Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,286 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Trigger heartbeat request.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.286304807Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,286 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Trigger heartbeat request.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.286438227Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,286 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderelection.DefaultLeaderElectionService [] - Confirm leader session ID b1730dc6-0f94-49f4-b519-56917f3027b7 for leader akka.tcp://flink@mta-flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_0.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.309361096Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,309 DEBUG org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesLeaderElectionDriver [] - Successfully wrote leader information: Leader=akka.tcp://flink@mta-flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/resourcemanager_0, session ID=b1730dc6-0f94-49f4-b519-56917f3027b7.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.320673232Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,320 INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.DefaultJobGraphStore [] - Retrieved job ids [] from KubernetesStateHandleStore{configMapName='mta-flink-dispatcher-leader'}
2020-12-29T06:45:54.3206989Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,320 INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.runner.SessionDispatcherLeaderProcess [] - Successfully recovered 0 persisted job graphs.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.324829616Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,324 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.SupervisorActor [] - Starting FencedAkkaRpcActor with name dispatcher_1.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.325343659Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,325 INFO org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcService [] - Starting RPC endpoint for org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher at akka://flink/user/rpc/dispatcher_1 .
2020-12-29T06:45:54.33778039Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,337 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.leaderelection.DefaultLeaderElectionService [] - Confirm leader session ID fbbaa883-69f6-43df-9ca0-c646bc1baad1 for leader akka.tcp://flink@mta-flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/dispatcher_1.
2020-12-29T06:45:54.36249763Z 2020-12-29 14:45:54,362 DEBUG org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesLeaderElectionDriver [] - Successfully wrote leader information: Leader=akka.tcp://flink@mta-flink-jobmanager:6123/user/rpc/dispatcher_1, session ID=fbbaa883-69f6-43df-9ca0-c646bc1baad1.
2020-12-29T06:46:04.298366262Z 2020-12-29 14:46:04,297 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Trigger heartbeat request.
2020-12-29T06:46:04.298442695Z 2020-12-29 14:46:04,298 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Trigger heartbeat request.
2020-12-29T06:46:14.318174464Z 2020-12-29 14:46:14,317 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Trigger heartbeat request.
2020-12-29T06:46:14.318256849Z 2020-12-29 14:46:14,318 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Trigger heartbeat request.
2020-12-29T06:46:24.337694477Z 2020-12-29 14:46:24,337 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Trigger heartbeat request.
2020-12-29T06:46:24.337816516Z 2020-12-29 14:46:24,337 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.resourcemanager.StandaloneResourceManager [] - Trigger heartbeat request.
2020-12-29T06:46:26.044624193Z 2020-12-29 14:46:26,044 DEBUG org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf [] - -Dorg.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.buffer.checkAccessible: true
```

Comment: we find the root cause is `kubernetes.namespace` is not configured correctly.

Comment: It looks as if the `DefaultLeaderRetrievalService.notifyLeaderAddress` isn't be called. Maybe somehow the `onModified` events are missed by the `KubernetesLeaderRetrievalDriver`. Is this the complete log file?

Comment: @HaydenZhou if you found a solution, it would be best to post that as an answer and mark it as accepted, so other people running into a similar problem can better understand how you solved it.